# How do I make multiple moving squares on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, object, animation

So far I have made a moving square that when the button is clicked in the HTML file, calls the draw() function and draws a red square in the canvas area that moves accross the canvas. How do I make it so that the same function draw() can create multiple moving sqaures?

Here's the code so far:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 10;

function draw(){ 
                 var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                 var ctx = can.getContext("2d");    
 var x = 1;

 setInterval(function(){ 
ctx.clearRect(0,0, can.width, can.height);
ctx.fillRect(x, 20, 75, 75);
ctx.fillStyle ="red";
x=x+5;    
 }, 500

 );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that my solution is good, I'm just starting to learn js, but hope it will helpful.

```js
// variables declaration. I suggest to use Arrays 
// for store individual rectangle parameters.

// rectangle start coords x and y
var rcx = [];
var rcy = [];

// delta to move x, y 
var dx = [];
var dy = [];

// rectangle size (if you want it variable)
var size =[];

// init canvas 
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// create and collect rectangles parameters 
// on window load (here 100 rectangles created)
// with unique coords, deltas to move,
// and sizes for each rectangle.
window.onload = function() {
        for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
            
            // in this solution all parameters randomized, 
            // but you can set whatever you want.
            rcx[i]=(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(canvas.width)));
            rcy[i]=(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(canvas.height)));
            dx[i]=  (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3))-1);
            dy[i]=(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3))-1);
            size[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(8)));
}};

// it is optional, but i decide 
// made function for rectangle declaration. 
// It will looks more compact when rendering.

function rect(x, y, size){
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, size, size/2 );
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";  
}


// finally all together into function draw()
function draw(){ 
    
        setInterval(function(){ 
            ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            
          
            for (var j=0; j<100; j++) {
                
                // read arrays
                // render rectangle with params from arrays
                rect(rcx[j],rcy[j],size[j]);
                
                // add delta to move (x,y) 
                // and rewrite new coords to arrays
                rcx[j]=rcx[j]+dx[j];
                rcy[j]=rcy[j]+dy[j]};
                
            
        }, 100

        );
        
    };

//rendering animation
draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        
        #canvas {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: #ccc; 
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="js1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't mention about button. So for the btn changes are simple.

1. Create btn div in html,
2. Add listener on this div. Рut params in arrays if button is pushed. Instead of generation by random as it was in my solution before.
3. Read arrays and render all rectangles from it.

```js
// variables declaration. I suggest to use Arrays for store individual rectangle parameters.

// rectangle start coords x and y
var rcx = [];
var rcy = [];

// delta to move x, y 
var dx = [];
var dy = [];

// rectangle size (if you want it variable)
var size =[];

//counter for created rectangles
var i=0;

// init canvas 
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// create and collect rectangles parameters on btn push 
// with unique coords, deltas to move, and sizes for each rectangle.

    var btn =document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
          
            //count every time you push the btn and create rect
            i=i+1;
            
            //generate rect params x,y, delta x, delta y, size
            rcx[i]=20;
            rcy[i]=20;
            dx[i]=1
            dy[i]=0
            size[i] = 8;
    
   });

// it is optional, but i decide made function for rectangle declaration. It will looks more compact when rendering.

function rect(x, y, size){
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, size, size/1.5);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";  
}


// finally all together into function draw()


function draw(){ 
    

    
        setInterval(function(){ 
            ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

          
            for (var j=1; j<rcx.length; j++) {

                // read arrays
                // render rectangle with params from arrays
                rect(rcx[j],rcy[j],size[j]);
                
                // add delta to move (x,y) and rewrite new coords to arrays
                rcx[j]=rcx[j]+dx[j];
                rcy[j]=rcy[j]+dy[j]};
                
            
        }, 100

        );
         
        
    };

//rendering animation
draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: rgb(17, 0, 28);
        }
        
        #container{
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
        #canvas {
            z-index: 0;
            position:fixed;
            align-self: center;
            justify-self: center;
            width: 80vw;
            height: 50vw;
            background-color: #ccc; 
        }
        
        #btn {
            margin: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
            padding: 10px;
            position:static; 
            top: 30px;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            width: 65px;
            background-color: brown;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
        #btn:hover {
            background-color: red;
        }
        
         #btn:active {
            background-color: coral;
        }
        
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="btn"> Push me </div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="js1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```